# Nginx override ngx_http_index_module directory index handling

Tags: nginx, configuration, redirect

Nginx v 1.4.6

autoindex off;

In an application having no central routing end-point, and for directories w/in the structure that have no index.* at all, I want to external redirect rather than 403 *Forbidden* or internal redirect.

```
app-root/
    app-core/
    config/
    lib/
    modules/
    templates/
index.php
```

Given the above, if none of app-core/ lib/ modules/ templates/ have an index.*, with no `server { location {}}` configuration coverage, any request to them results in a 402 forbidden response. *Yucky.*

With this config, I can internally redirect to an actual index.

```
location ~* ^/(app-core|config|lib|modules|templates)/$ {
    index /;
}
```

So an request to `http://localhost:xxxx/lib/` serves the app-root/index.php shown above. *Fair enough but I think it could be better.*

I would rather issue a 303 *See Other* and redirect to `http://localhost:xxxx/` but I cannot figure out how to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work with this:

```
location ~* ^/(app-core|config|lib|modules|templates)/$ {
    return 303 http://localhost:xxxx/;
}
```

Comment: actually i ended up with: ```return 303 $scheme://$host:$server_port/;```